# delete the last blank page of a word document

Tags: microsoft-word

So I know there are tons of how-to instruction on the internet, but unfortunately, none seems to work exactly. So I am on a Mac(big Sur) and I have a word file that I need to edit. Precisely, I need to delete the last few pages. And it seems I am unable to delete the last blank page. [image] As I have learned from the internet, I first typed Command+8 to show paragraph mark, and then try to delete the mark. But for somereason, I seem unable to od that. It is possible this is because my keyboard doesn't have a del button, only a backspace button.[image]

See the original file if anyone need it to debug. https://1drv.ms/w/s!Asmw5jmhBIp7hXgMozT--3VzMFjN?e=AP9r1L

Comment: Are you trying to delete the one in blue? Have you tried to select with your mouse the content of the last page then press backspace to delete it?

Comment: Yes, doesn't work I believe

Comment: See this page by Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill: http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/BlankPage.htm

Answer (score 1):

I download the test paper, it seems that the sealing line on the left is too long.

Please try to Layout tab Margines > Custom Margines > Set 1.57cm for both of Top and Bottom.

[image]

And then go to Layout tab on this windows, choose "Continous" for "Section Start".

On my Mac environment, after operating the above 2 steps, the last blank page will automatically disappear.

[image]